# I just would like someone to double check my working.

Tags: geometry

Recently, I was given this problem for homework and I have completed it but I am unsure of my answer's correctness. Here is the problem:

The length of a rectangular kitchen is y meters and the width is x meters. If the kitchen is half the square of its width and its perimeter is 48 meters, find the values of x and y.

My answer for X is 6 meters and my answer for Y is 18 meters. All I would like to know is if I'm correct or not and any working provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time even if you don't answer this :)

Comment: "The kitchen is half the square of its width" - what does this mean?

Comment: Did you mean that the area is $\frac 12x^2?$ If so, the answer is incorrect.

Comment: I think he means "length of the kitchen". And then the answer is fine

Comment: @injusticefellow: If you would have shown how you got the answer, it would have helped some people understand the problem and your thought process.

Comment: @Andrei this is my working.
In the question it is stated that the length of the kitchen is Y meters and the width is X meters 
It is also stated that the length of the kitchen is alf te quare of its width and its perimeter is 48 meters. This is where This is where Peter Foreman 's question came in. I miscopied it and the question states that the length of the kitchen is half the square of its width. With the logic and misprints out of the way, here is my working:

Comment: (Post is too long for one comment)
Len.=1/2w^2
therefore y=1/2x^2
perimeter=48 meters long
since the area is a rectangle,
2(x+y)=48 meters
x+y=24 Meters     (This is equation A)
since y=1/2x^2     (Equation B)
Substitute Equation B into A
x+(1/2x^2)=24 Meters
(1/2x^2)+x-24=0
Numbers that satisfy that equation are: 6 or -8 Meters respectively
since a length cannot be less than zero and no reference point for dirrection is given in the equation, the length must be more than zero. Hence, I used six.
Substitute x=6 meters into equation A
6+y=24
Hence y is 18 meters

Comment: @PeterForeman I have corrected any mistakes present in the equation. I would also like to thank everyone who took time out of their days to answer my question as I have no one else to ask these questions to.

Comment: Your solution is correct

Comment: @andei thank you for the confirmation